# Add timestamp to html file in R

Tags: html, r, dataframe, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have a set of html files which are generated as a output. The names of the html output files should be the timestamps. I am able to generate the date using the following code.

```
DT::SaveWidget(Output, paste0(Sys.date(), ".html"))
```

I want the time as well. But I get an error "Cannot create file, reason: 'Invalid argument'"

```
DT::SaveWidget(Output, paste0(Sys.time(), ".html"))
```

I also tried the following way:

```
now <- Sys.time() 
DT :: SaveWidget(Output,paste0(now, "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_"), ".html")
```

It is throwing the same error. Is there a way to append the time to the html output files. It is for a set of files in folder. So, it should be different for each file. Kindly suggest a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason probably is that `as.character(Sys.time())` contains colons which are not allowed in file names (at least on Windows).
You could try this:

```
htmlwidgets::SaveWidget(Output, paste0(format(Sys.time(), "%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S"), ".html"))
```

Comment: I tried it but it is throwing an  Error: 'SaveWidget' is not an exported object from 'namespace:DT'.

Comment: DT is a datatable. I have successfully converted the datatable to html . Now i have to name the html with its respective timestamp

Comment: This is because `SaveWidget` is not a function from the `DT` package but from the `htmlwidgets` package. So try `htmlwidgets::SaveWidget`